# Use HTTP DELETE in symfony production environnement

Tags: php, rest, symfony, routes, symfony-routing

i have a rest api, based on symfony 2.3.
It works nice on debug mode but if i switch to prod env, i always get a 501 response error with this message "This method may not be used." on DELETE Http request (get works fine).

I check the configuration, got:

config.yml:

> http_method_override => true

Here is my routing:

```
test_delete:
    path:   /categories
    defaults: { _controller: OMGAPIBundle:GET\GetCategory:deleteTest }
    requirements:
        _method:  DELETE
```

And my controller:

```
public function deleteTestAction(){
    return new Response(1);
}
```

Comment: are you working on port `80` ?

Comment: Not sure if it will help your profile  but you should be using `methods: [DELETE]` instead of `requirements:_method: DELETE` to set the allowed/required method(s).

Comment: @Qoop i tried to replace requirements:_method: DELETE by methods: [DELETE] and even tried both :p nothing changed :s

Comment: @ra_htial seems stupid, i don't even know where i should check that :p but we are using https so i'm not sure.

Comment: Are you routing your controller right? If you change the request to GET, does it works?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken it's the `https` can you try to run it over `http` ?

Comment: I think i found it, this is a pound bad configuration:
http://www.apsis.ch/pound/ i'll check that.

@facundoFasciolo yes, POST and GET works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test_delete:
    pattern: /categories
    defaults: { _controller: OMGAPIBundle:YourControllerName:deleteTest }
    methods: [DELETE]
```

Obviusly, your controller must be written like this:

```
class YourControllerNameController{
    ...
    public function deleteTestAction(){
        return new Response(1);
    }
    ...
}
```

And be sure that you are sending a DELETE request...

Answer (score 0):

This was a bad pound configuration. It works now :)

=> http://www.apsis.ch/pound/